Is there a subscription list for entities to be notified of new patent applications so that they can challenge the new claims?
For example, let's take Match Group Inc, which is a multi billion dollar conglomerate group that owns a suite of dating apps.
Is there a list that they sign on to on the USTPO that notifies them of a patent application that claims inventions in the dating app space so that Match Group could challenge it if one of their dating apps have already invented it?

Anyone can set a search string at a patent searching site and schedule it to run daily. Not a service of the USPTO but a feature of most search engines.See Google Alerts to set this up for regular Google searches, for example.
The Lens is a search site that allows sophisticated alerts to be set.
When first filed patent applications are confidential and can’t be seen by searches. Once published (usually 18 months from earliest priority date) they become visible. If filed only in the U.S. it is possible to avoid publication until and unless a patent is actually issued.
To automatically follow amendments made after publication would be more difficult and probably would need to be done by hand once an application was first identified.
The U.S. does not have a mechanism for active pre-issue challenges like the EPO. There is way for third parties to submit prior art during a certain time window to the examiner in a way that requires the examiner to considerate submission. However there is no back and forth interaction.
It can be done anonymously with no or little cost. This mechanism was put in place by the 2012 AIA law and was a key part of the motivation for Ask Patents to be created. Over the years Ask Patents questions and answers have mostly left behind its original motivation which was weeding out software invention applications that were not novel.
If a counterpart EPO application is pending you can file “observations” over a longer time window and the applicator will be required to bring those observations to the attic the U.S. examiner.

As long as you create a free account, the Lens allows pretty fine grained automated search reports.
